# How to speedup the startup of IIS Express in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

Is there anyway to somehow speedup my IIS Express when debugging/starting my application on Visual Studio Community Edition 2019?

Most of the cases startup happens after a couple of minutes and sometimes more, and after that I also have to wait another minute to let my application loads in the browser.

Comment: There is a lot happening behind the scene which you have no control of, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 so the only feasible to speed it up is to use a more powerful machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'll get heat for this, but a major part of the problem is that IIS Express is just slow. It's super frustrating, since even on a brand new, clean project it can take a painfully long time to start up. Faster hardware will help a little, but that isn't always an option.

You can start without debugging if all you need is the server. If things are still painfully slow, I've had some luck deleting the .vs folder in the project and restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I have had some luck speeding up IISexpress debugging sessions doing a few things:

1. **Setup some Anti-virus realtime protection exception rules** for Visual Studio and IIS Express.  If you are using Windows Defender, Braytiner de Souza Heggendorn has excellent Powershell scripts on his [GitHub Repo](https://gist.github.com/Braytiner)
2. **Turn Off IIS Express httpLoggin.** Edit applicationhost.config at %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config\

```html
<httpLogging dontLog="true" />
```

Comment: This has fasten our build up time from approximately 06:30min to 03:30min. Thank you.